# Casting HTML Object elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, checkbox

I am trying to tick a checkbox which is inside the first cell of a tablerow.

```
var checkbox = $(this).find("td").eq(0);
```

returns an [Object object] but when I use the html() function it is clear that it returns only the code for the input element.

Is it possible to cast the variable checkbox so that I can then check it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting `[Object object]` because `.eq()` returns a jQuery object.

You're getting HTML code with `.html()` because that is a method of the jQuery object, which returns the HTML inside an element (similar to raw Javascript `.innerHTML()`).

To get the raw HTML DOM element from a jQuery object, you can try something like:

```
var rawDomElement = $(this).find('td')[0];
```

#### EDIT

But if you want to check a checkbox, you can try calling `.attr('checked', true)` on a jQuery object representing the checkbox DOM element.

Comment: Thanks! That works, I'll mark it as correct as soon as it lets me. 
I'm also a bit confused as to whether I should be changing the DOM element or the jQuery object. I guess the result is the same but which is better practice?

Comment: Most arguments on RAW vs jQuery wrapped objects revolve around performance reasons, I think. Most of the time, it's completely negligible. For your case, I'd say you've already got a jQuery object; not much sense in switching to RAW for something as trivial as checking a checkbox (which isn't that trivial at all when considering cross-browser nuances --- something that jQuery attempts to normalize).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var checkbox = $(this).find("td:first :input[type=checkbox]");
checkbox.prop('checked',!checkbox.prop('checked'));
```

And I recommend you use jquery's [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method instead of the `attr` one.

Comment: Mmm, I tried this but I get an error message
"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'attr"

Answer (score 1):

```
var checkbox = $(this).find("td:first").find(':checkbox');
```